# MS SQL sp_add_schedule specify multiple frequency intervals

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, schedule, job-scheduling

I need to build a script that creates a new job schedule that runs weekly, Monday-Friday.

I've already attempted to use SSMS to script this but for some reason, only shows "@freq_interval=62", which doesn't appear in the list of possible days of the week.

exec msdb.dbo.sp_add_schedule @schedule_name=N'WB:CovergeDataFiles', @freq_type=8, @freq_interval=(2 or 4 or 8 or 16 or 32),@active_start_time=50000;

As you and I would expect, I receive an "incorrect syntax" error - as I'm pretty sure that the syntax is wrong.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Perhaps it's a sum of the numerical equivalent of the days? 2 = Monday, 4 = Tuesday, 8 = Wednesday, 16 = Thursday, 32 = Friday - which is 62?

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question but perhaps this will help someone else. Below, is a M-F job schedule that runs at 5AM. Just, change the schedule name. MSDN is misleading, you have to sum the numerical values of the days of the week.

2 = Monday + 4 = Tuesday + 8 = Wednesday + 16 = Thursday + 32 = Friday = 62

This, "62" is the value for @freq_interval. See below:

```
exec exec msdb.dbo.sp_add_schedule @schedule_name=N'{Name}', @freq_type=8, @freq_interval=62, @freq_recurrence_factor=1, @active_start_time=50000;
```